# Can't access the second image because of same id

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to replace the image by clicking on it and using getElementById but it is only replacing the first image even when I click the second image because of the same ids but I tried using class and getElementsByClassName also and it is not working. What should I do to replace second image when I click on it?

```
<html>

<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" id="img1" onclick="replaceImage()"/>
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" id="img1" onclick="replaceImage()"/>

<script>
    function replaceImage(){
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png";
                    
}
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique. Either make them different or use a different way to access the elements.

Comment: Id's are unique, you can use classes.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, I mentioned that using same id is creating the problem and I tried class too but it is not working and I don't know why, Is there any other different way to make this work?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal using Class is not even replacing the first image

Comment: @Fenaz Do you want it toggleable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img1");

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgs[i].src = "https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Note This is not important. */
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" class="img1" />
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" class="img1" />
```

---

**If you want it toggleable you can do this:**

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img1");

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgs[i].classList.toggle("bookmarked");
    if (imgs[i].classList.contains("bookmarked")) {
      imgs[i].src = "https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png";
    } else {
      imgs[i].src =
        "https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Note This is not important. */
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" class="img1" />
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" class="img1" />
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" class="img1" />
```

Comment: Thanks Man, excellent answer and also thanks for toggle, I was trying to do it and failed. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you shouldnt be using same id on both image tags. Also i see that you are using the absolute same code twice, Thats not recommended.
However if you use getElementsByClass as the name suggests you get an array back which contains all elements with this class.
[elem1, elem2]
Now select the one you like to update using [ ] Operator

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please pay attention to the typos and organization of the content. Better you read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tell you about the IDs needing to be unique.  I feel like that ground has been covered by other people, and they're right.  That said, try something like this:

```html
<html>

    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" id="img1" 
        onclick="replaceImage(this)"/>
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png" id="img1" 
        onclick="replaceImage(this)"/>

    <script>
        function replaceImage(e){
            e.src = "https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/bookmark-ribbon.png";            
        }
    </script>

<html>
```